# How to get response header in RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

In the controller, I use

```
JsonNoderesponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonNode.class)
```

However I got a 'Cannot extract response: no Content-Type found' exception.

After debugging, I found the error comes from `HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData()` where the `respose.getHeaders().getContentType()` is null.

So I want to print out the header to see what is missing. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Use `getForEntity` instead of `getForObject`.

Comment: My controller calls a backend REST app.The controller code is:    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
response = restTemplate.getForObject(RESTAPPURL, JsonNode.class);              I verify that the rest app is working fine.  But the getForObject function throws a 'no Content-type' exception, so I couldn't get any response from the controller.

Comment: The exception traced back to HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extracData(ClientHTTPResponse) fucntion in restTemplate.excute(). in extractData() function, response.getHeaders().getContentType() ==null and throws the exception. So I am wondering if there is a way I can get the response header before the exception